# C++ - Moving generated numbers into a string

Tags: c++, string

I have a code that generates some numbers, and now I need to count how frequent they are. For example, the code will generate 100000 numbers, and i need to know how many times does 0 appear, 1, 2... I know that this can be done with strings, but im having a problem turning those values into one big string.
You see, all the generated numbers will be the same variable G, so if a ask to turn G into a string, Im going to have a string of the very last number assigned to G, and not of all of them, that is beacuse the variable G changes value each time its printed, because it is inside a loop. is there any way for me to move ALL the printed values into one big string? (If 100000 is too much for a string, i can generate less numbers with little problem)

This is the code

```
int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,A,B,C,D,E,F,G;

srand(time(NULL));
int seed = rand();
default_random_engine ran { static_cast <int>( chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count())};
default_random_engine ran_2 { static_cast <int>( chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count())};
uniform_int_distribution <int> range {1,50};

a=range (ran);
b = 2;
c = 107;
d = 109;
e = 113;
f = 167;
g = 173;
h = 587;
i = 13; 

for ( k=0; k < 100000; k++) {

    srand(time(NULL));
    int seed = rand();
    default_random_engine ran { static_cast <int>( chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count())};
    default_random_engine ran_2 { static_cast <int>( chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count())};
        uniform_int_distribution <int> range {1,50};
    a=range (ran);

b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;
c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;
d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;
e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;
f++;    f++;
g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;
h--;    h--;    h--;    h--;    h--;    h--;    h--;    h--;    h--;    h--;    h--;
i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;

       A= (a*b*c*f);
       B= ((A^13)/d*h-i^a);
       C= (A*B^i-b*h*g*e*a);
       D= (b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i)*a;
       E= ((a*A*B*C*D)/100000000);
       F= E % 10;
       if ( F < 0 ) { G = F*(-1); } else { G = F; }

       cout << G;
}
```

}

Thank you very much! :) Have a great day

Comment: What the heck is this `b++;    b++;    b++;   ...` code ??

Comment: I have literally no idea what's going on here.

Comment: Translated into English, `int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,A,B,C,D,E,F,G;` means "I need an array."

Comment: `b += 746` is an idea that comes to mind instead of this whole `b++; b++; ...` thing.

Comment: Why don't you just stick them in a `std::map<int, int>` where the index is the random number generated and the value is a count you increase every time you get that number. Then getting the counts is just a matter of iterating the map and printing out the key:value pairs..? Btw; `srand`/`rand` produce horribly bad quality random numbers. Use the stuff from the `<random>` header instead.

Comment: You should not be calling `srand(time(NULL))` on every loop iteration.  Call it ONLY ONCE at program startup instead.

Comment: I think you may be overthinking this. You need to count the the frequency of a large number of randomly generated number, yes?

Comment: @OP --  Honestly, this can be done in around 5 lines using a `std::map<int, int>`, and without all of those variables that boggle the mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if a ask to turn G into a string, Im going to have a string of the very last number assigned to G, and not of all of them

Simply declare a separate `std::string` variable that your loop can append to each time a new number is assigned to `G`, eg:

```
std::string everything;
...
G = ...;
everything += std::to_string(G);
...
```

Then after the loop is finished, you can loop through `everything` counting the characters as needed.

Or, consider using a `std::map` keyed by digit chars, and let it handle the counting for you:

```
std::map<char, int> counter;
...
G = ...;
for (char ch : std::to_string(G))
    counter[ch]++;
...
```

Or, just use a fixed array indexed by digits:

```
int counter[10];
...
G = ...;
for (char ch : std::to_string(G))
    counter[ch-'0']++;
...
```

Either way, after the loop is finished, you can then loop through `counter` to retrieve the counts of each digit.

Answer (score 2):

> and i need to know how many times does 0 appear, 1, 2...

And to achieve that you should not store all numbers into one huge string, but you better have `int` array with 10 elements (one counter for each digit) and increase each accordingly when new number generated - at the end you have all your counters:

```
std::vector<int> counters( 10 );
...
for( auto c : std::to_string( G ) )
    ++counters[ c - '0' ];

// at the end all counters in the vector
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do that with strings but hashmap should help here (see below); The cons of this is the mem consumption. With a large number of probes and really random values, you can end up with memory allocation problem.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>

int main()
{
  std::unordered_map<int, int> histogram;
  std::unordered_map<int, int>::iterator it;

  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      int v = rand();
      if (histogram.find(v) == histogram.end()) {
          histogram[v] = 0;
      }
      histogram[v]++;
  }

 for (it = histogram.begin(); it != histogram.end(); it++ ) {
        std::cout << "VALUE:" << it->first  // number
              << "\t FREQ:"
              << it->second   // frequency
              << std::endl ;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the asker's case the generated numbers appear to be [1,50]. This makes a map overkill. A simple 50 element array will do the job.

Comment: Right. That' s depends on the range of probes. In case of small amount of probes simple array is enou.

Answer (score -2):

you need to have a variable living out side of your function that you can append to every time the loop runs. when the loop finishes than you will have all of the content stored inside of that str: variable

```
    int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,A,B,C,D,E,F,G;

srand(time(NULL));
int seed = rand();
default_random_engine ran { static_cast <int>( chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count())};
default_random_engine ran_2 { static_cast <int>( chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count())};
uniform_int_distribution <int> range {1,50};

a=range (ran);
b = 2;
c = 107;
d = 109;
e = 113;
f = 167;
g = 173;
h = 587;
i = 13; 
std::string str;
for ( k=0; k < 100000; k++) {

srand(time(NULL));
int seed = rand();
default_random_engine ran { static_cast <int>( chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count())};
default_random_engine ran_2 { static_cast <int>( chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count())};
    uniform_int_distribution <int> range {1,50};
a=range (ran);

b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;    b++;
c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;    c++;
d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;    d++;
e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;    e++;
f++;    f++;
g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;   g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;    g--;
h--;    h--;    h--;    h--;    h--;    h--;    h--;    h--;    h--;    h--;    h--;
i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;    i--;
   A= (a*b*c*f);
   B= ((A^13)/d*h-i^a);
   C= (A*B^i-b*h*g*e*a);
   D= (b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i)*a;
   E= ((a*A*B*C*D)/100000000);
   F= E % 10;
   if ( F < 0 ) { G = F*(-1); } else { G = F; }

   cout << G;
   str.append(G)
}

cout << str;
```

Comment: Why on earth is your answer code still calling `srand` and `rand`? What's wrong with `std::random_device`? Also; *please* don't use `std::default_random_engine` - *ever* - you don't know what it will be and it may be just as bad as `rand()` - name the engine you want explicitly - most likely `std::mt19937` or `std::19937_64`.

Comment: Because i have limited C++ experience and was attempting to solve the problem that was given by the user. If he wants an entire code review, that is great. But thats not what i was trying to do, nor is it what was requested. I could be wrong, but i think he asked how to get all the numbers into one large string......